Swagger OpenApi Authorization code flow with auth0 and spring security
I'm having issues with configuring openapi (swagger) to use authorizationCode flow with auth0 as security provider. On auth0 side I've configured API and application (Machine2machine type)
Below is the error I'm getting plus my config:

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="An
error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Encrypted JWT
rejected: No JWE key selector is
configured",error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

    private static final String OAUTH_SCHEME_NAME = "oauth";

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customizeOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                .addList(OAUTH_SCHEME_NAME))
            .components(new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes(OAUTH_SCHEME_NAME, createOAuthScheme()))
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(OAUTH_SCHEME_NAME));
    }

    private SecurityScheme createOAuthScheme() {
        return new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2).flows(createOAuthFlows());
    }

    private OAuthFlows createOAuthFlows() {
        OAuthFlow scopes = new OAuthFlow()
            .authorizationUrl("https://dev-xxxxxx.us.auth0.com/authorize")
            .refreshUrl("https://dev-xxxxxx.us.auth0.com/oauth/token")
            .tokenUrl("https://dev-xxxxxx.us.auth0.com/oauth/token")
            .scopes(new Scopes());
        return new OAuthFlows().authorizationCode(scopes);
    }
}

Security config:
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

private final Auth0JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
private String issuerUri;

private final Auth0AudienceValidator audienceValidator;

private final Auth0SignatureValidator signatureValidator;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
            req.requestMatchers(getPermittedMatchers()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
        .cors(withDefaults())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .oauth2ResourceServer(auth -> auth.jwt(token -> token.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)));

    return http.build();
}

private String[] getPermittedMatchers() {
    return securityProperties.getPermittedMatchers().toArray(String[]::new);
}

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> issuerValidator = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> delegate = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(issuerValidator, audienceValidator,
        signatureValidator);

    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(delegate);

    return jwtDecoder;
}

YAML:
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://dev-xxxx.us.auth0.com/
          audiences: https://userapi
          jwk-set-uri: https://dev-xxxx.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      client-id: ${auth0.client-id}
      client-secret: ${auth0.client-secret}
    oauth2-redirect-url: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html

